# I need to change the order and values of columns of a .txt file without any headers

Tags: powershell, header, multiple-columns, txt

I have a IExport.txt file with one or more lines of numbers and letters separated by semicolon and a total of 14 columns.
**The file has no headers and i need it to be like this**

```
4;1613000026438;T0011368;1.00;715004978;922105;;101120;;171;Name0;Thing1;Name1;989105
```

This is what i **imagine** the file to look like (part of it):

```
H1 H2            H3       H4   H5        H6     H7    H8
-- ------------- -------- ---- --------- ------ ----- ---
4  1613000026438 T0011368 1.00 715004978 922105
```

I need to change the file as follows:
Column 7 to 14 shall be deleted
Value "1.00" in column 4 shall be set to "1"
And the columns shall be reordered like this:

```
H1 H3       H4 H2            H5        H6
-- -------- -- ------------- --------- ------
4  T0011368 1  1613000026438 715004978 922105
```

I need the file in the end like this:

```
4;T0011368;1;1613000026438;715004978;922105
```

I want to change the file as stated above, but without any headers and rename it from "IExport.txt" to "KExport.txt".
**Is there a way to reorder the columns without naming them?**

I have edited my question, because i understand i didn't provide enough information and because i don't need the headers anymore.

I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Please show us a better (formatted) example of the file and also the desired output

Comment: @Theo i edited the question to bettwer show my need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in this case you want an output file without quotes or header, you can use Import-Csv to read and parse the input file and then output a series of chosen items joined with `;` in the order you need

Try:

```
$fileIn = 'X:\Somewhere\IExport.txt'
$result = Import-Csv -Path $fileIn -Delimiter ';' -Header (1..6 | ForEach-Object { "H$_" }) |
          ForEach-Object {
             # reorder the fields, use [int] on H4 and output a semi-colon delimited string
             $_.H1, $_.H3, [int]$_.H4, $_.H2, $_.H5, $_.H6 -join ';'
         }
# output the new file
$fileOut = $fileIn -replace 'IExport\.txt$', 'XExport.txt'
$result | Set-Content -Path $fileOut
```

Result using your example:

```
4;T0011368;1;1613000026438;715004978;922105
```

Comment: This works very well. Can i However also import 8 Headers?
`4;1613000026438;T0011368;1.00;715004978;922105;;101120`  
and give the following result:  
`4;T0011368;1;1613000026438;715004978;922105;;`

Comment: @John919 Sure, just change `1..6` into `1..8` and add `$_.H7, $_.H8` to the array you're outputting (in any order  you like). Don't forget to separate the elements with a comma

Comment: @John919 If you want to omit some fields like `H8` in your comment, just put `$null` or an empty string in its place.

Comment: This works for me and is actually not that hard. appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

***'Dilly B'***, as per my comment, here's what I mean.

***'John919'***, is this what you are after?

```
Clear-Host
'4;1613000026438;T0011368;1.00;715004978;922105;;101120;;171;Name0;Thing1;Name1;989105' | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' -header H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6 | 
# Results
<#
H1 : 4
H2 : 1613000026438
H3 : T0011368
H4 : 1.00
H5 : 715004978
H6 : 922105
#>
Select-Object -Property @{
    Name       = 'Row'
    Expression = {$PSItem.H1} 
}, H3, @{
    Name       = 'H4'
    Expression = {($PSItem.H4) -replace '\.\d+'} 
}, H2, H5, H6 | 
# Results
<#
Row : 4
H3  : T0011368
H4  : 1
H2  : 1613000026438
H5  : 715004978
H6  : 922105
#>
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
Row H3       H4 H2            H5        H6    
--- --       -- --            --        --    
4   T0011368 1  1613000026438 715004978 922105
#>
```

Of course ***'John919'***, other than the `Format-Table` things, you can just do what you say you are after.

```
Export-csv -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\KExport.txt" -NoTypeInformation
Import-Csv -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\KExport.txt"
```

Yet, as you can see, one can do this on the fly and manipulate it further as one chooses, without the need to serialize the results to the file system.

Comment: this works very well, however i made some little adjustments to my question.

Answer (score 1):

By using semicolon as delimiter you could do it.

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\sample.txt -Header 1,2,3,4,5,6 -Delimiter ';'
```

Export it as a csv and import again with your desired order like 1,3,6,2,5,4

Comment: ***'@Dilly B'*** one can skip the export-import and just convert on the fly.  ***'John919'***,  you really show what your actual output should be as well, just as you showed the input, thus avoiding the need for us to guess. Especially the whole delete thing as you are not showing that at all. What you show is you using it all. BTW, don't use integers as headers, as that just causes issues. Headers really should be just stringsd